# Refresh cart_fragments(mini-cart) by PHP or jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to update the mini-cart (cart_fragments) after/on an ajax event. It works like this.

HTML Trigger:

```
<a id="woomps-button-\'.$nr.\'" class="woomps-button" '.$ajax_url.' data-button-nr="'.$nr.'">
```

jQuery request:

```
jQuery( document ).on('click', '.woomps-button', function() {
    var nr= jQuery(this).data('button-nr');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : subpost.ajax_url,
        type : 'post',
        data : {
            action : 'woomps_update_nr',
            security : subpost.security,
            nr: nr
        },
        success : function( response ) {
            window.alert(nr);
            //MAYBE_code to refresh_fragments here
            }
    });
    return false;
});
```

PHP responder:

```
function woomps_update_choosen_person () {
    $p = $_POST['nr'];
    if ($p == 1) {$x= "This must show in cart";}
    WC()->session->set( 'woomps_limit_by_persons' , $x );

    //MAYBE code to refresh_fragments here
}
```

And in the mini-cart.php template i have a calculation based on this field.

```
$items_left_start = WC()->session->get( 'woomps_limit_by_persons' )?: 3 ;
//Do something something here
```

So this works, except I need to refresh the cart like when an item is added to cart. My assumption is that is should be an ajax request from jQuery that i can put in the success block?

The class i (think) I want to fire is this `WC_AJAX::get_refreshed_fragments();` But this is fired from an an add_action, so i tried this `add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_woocommerce_get_refreshed_fragments', array( 'WC_AJAX', 'get_refreshed_fragments' ) );`. But it did not work either.

I also try to create an jQuery ajax call like it does in the add_to_cart button, but it neither worked.

```
//MAYBE_code to refresh_fragments here
        var data = {};
        jQuery.post(
            wc_get_refreshed_fragments_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().
            replace( '%%endpoint%%', 'get_refreshed_fragments' ), data,
            function( response ){

            })

        }
```

I do not completely understand how this works, if anyone have some pointers or a snippet i would so much appriciate it. Been struggeling with this for some time now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much struggeling [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556451/update-woocommerce-cart-after-adding-variable-product-via-ajax/) on stack helped create the correct code to update mini cart fragments. It was both PHP and jQuery neeeded.

So basically you can call the `WC_AJAX::get_refreshed_fragments()` at the end of your PHP coode responder; if it comes from an AJAX call. It will not return to your PHP responder code so put it at the end. The PHP respons will end/sent back to jQuery inside the `WC_AJAX::get_refreshed_fragments()`; so you also need to create some jQuery that responds to this. This i got from the [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556451/update-woocommerce-cart-after-adding-variable-product-via-ajax/):

```
 var fragments = response.fragments;

 if ( fragments ) {

                jQuery.each(fragments, function(key, value) {
                    jQuery(key).replaceWith(value);
                });

            }
```