# How to customise Order Quantity output in Woocommerce product page

Tags: woocommerce, orders

I have specific design which should converted to Woocommerce. I stuck on order quantity part of it. The final design should be [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPvIv.png)

I searched through the internet and didn't find any relevant topic. there was something about turning it to Select Input which worked great, but not anything about my desired output.

So any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantity input template is located at `woocommerce/global/quantity-input.php`.
You can add plus and minus html in quantity-input.php.

For more detail, please check this tutorial.
http://wcodex.co.in/add-plus-minus-quantity-increment-woocommerce-store/

There is also a question: [Add plus and minus buttons to WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583213/add-plus-and-minus-buttons-to-woocommerce)

Comment: Thank you @ucheng, That is very good resource. Just what I needed.